# Function that returns the same object shape as it accepted in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to constrain a function such that it accept an object as an argument, and returns an object of the exact same shape.  That object's keys can be any string, and I'd like to tell typescript that the return object has the same keys.  I.e.

```
interface ConstrainedObject {
  [key: string]: string[];
}

function transformer(argument: ConstrainedObject): ConstrainedObject {
  // ... code here
}
```

So really this function can accept an object whose keys are *any* string, but it should enforce that the return value has the same keys.  I.e.

```
const result = transformer({
  linda: ['1', '2', '3'],
  jacob: ['4', '5', '6']
})

result.linda; // allowed, and intellisense should help here
result.jeremy // should error, as the object passed to transformer did not have this key
```

Is this possible in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you label something `Record<string, string[]>` or the mapped type you have you are saying *specifically* to the compiler that this object has a loose schema. Just don't do that. Then you can combine the inferred type of the object with a generic constraint:

```
function transform<T extends Record<string, string[]>>(x: T): T {
    // modify x
    return x;
}
```

now when you call it

```
const x = transform({
  foo: ['a', 'b'],
});
```

you can reference `x.foo` and will compile, have autocompletion, etc. We have a type `T` that we know matches the schema you set but the compiler can infer a *more specific* type (in this case `{ foo: string[] }`) for `T`.

If you want `transform` to be more general you can replace `string[]` with `unknown` in the generic constraint and it will work more generally, although for anything other than the identity function the implementation might get tricky.

```
function transform2<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(x: T): T {
  // modify x
  return x;
}

const y = transform2({
  a: true,
  b: 'hi',
  c: 5
});

const { a, b, c } = y;
console.log(a); // true
console.log(b.repeat(2)); // compiler knows it's a string, can call string method
console.log(c.toFixed(2)); // same for number here
```